# C++ variable can't be duplicated from a variable

Tags: c++

`p1_choice` variable stores data correctly, but can't replicate\overwrite  the `ttt` array.

I want to store the data gained from the user in `p1_choice` variable to `ttt[0}` array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

//CREATING VARIABLES
string ttt[9] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
string p1_choice;
int p2_choice;
int gametime = 20;

int main()
{
    while (gametime < 21) {
        cout << endl;
        gametime++;
        cout << "::: " << ttt[0] << " :: " << ttt[1] << " :: " << ttt[2] << " :::" << endl;
        cout << "::: " << ttt[3] << " :: " << ttt[4] << " :: " << ttt[5] << " :::" << endl;
        cout << "::: " << ttt[6] << " :: " << ttt[7] << " :: " << ttt[8] << " :::" << endl;

        cout << "PLAYER 1 ENTER YOUR COICE HERE........";
        cin >> p1_choice;
        cout << p1_choice << endl;
        p1_choice = ttt[6];
        cout << "::: " << ttt[6]
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p1_choice = ttt[6];` did you mean `ttt[6] = p1_choice;`?

Comment: i edited my question so you understand better.

Comment: i want to store data from p1_choice to ttt[6]

Comment: So why do you have the assignment backwards? Your code stores the data from ttt[6] to p1_choice.

Comment: Please read [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite a variable you have to use the assign operator this way:
var_to_overwrite = new_value;

You did the opposite in your code.